# Regex - How can you identify strings which are not words?

Tags: regex, nlp

Got an interesting one, and can't come up with any solid ideas, so thought maybe someone else may have done something similar.

I want to be able to identify strings of letters in a longer sentence that are not words and remove them.  Essentially things like `kuashdixbkjshakd`

Everything annoyingly is in lowercase which makes it more difficult, but since I only care about English, I'm essentially looking for the opposite of consonant clusters, groups of them that don't make phonetically pronounceable sounds.

Has anyone heard of/done something like this before?

EDIT: this is what ChatGpt tells me

> It is difficult to provide a comprehensive list of combinations of consonants that have never appeared in a word in the English language. The English language is a dynamic and evolving language, and new words are being created all the time. Additionally, there are many regional and dialectal variations of the language, which can result in different sets of words being used in different parts of the world.

> It is also worth noting that the frequency of use of a particular combination of consonants in the English language is difficult to quantify, as the existing literature on the subject is limited. The best way to determine the frequency of use of a particular combination of consonants would be to analyze a large corpus of written or spoken English.

> In general, most combinations of consonants are used in some words in the English language, but some combinations of consonants may be relatively rare. Some examples of relatively rare combinations of consonants in English include "xh", "xw", "ckq", and "cqu". However, it is still possible that some words with these combinations of consonants exist.

Comment: Regex is perhaps not a fruitful avenue for this particular task. If you are working on a particular language, you can try to articulate its syllabic structure; but this will then misfire on loan words or brand names with different spelling (like for English, "vkontakte" or "hryvnia" or "schadenfreude" or, well, "tumblr").

Comment: "_consonant clusters_"... such like [rhythm](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rhythm)?

Comment: What language/tool are you using? How long is a "consonant cluster", which you would probably count "y" as a vowel. "Witchcraft" has 5 in a row. Is 6 your limit?

Comment: A consonant cluster is a group of consonants that make a specific sound like ch th etc.  I was looking for some that don't make speakable sounds, but that seems like it may be impossible.

Comment: I think regex is the wrong tool for the job here. It can never develop or change on its own and like ChatGPT said language will do such things. That said I think the best alternative here is a dictionary/auto-correction service either locally or online depending on your performance requirements and target system.

Comment: If you ask ChatGPT for an explanation you should ask it also for the regex. I bet it's as incompetent as naming "_xh_" and "_xw_" as rare without seeing [foxhole](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/foxhole) and [waxwing](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/waxwing) right away. Consider using https://english.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

You could try to pass every single word inside the sentence to a function that checks wether the word is listed inside a dictionary. There is a good number of dictionary text files on GitHub. To speed up the process: use a hash map :)

You could also use an auto-corretion API or a library.

Algorithm to combine both methods:

1. Run sentence through auto correction
2. Run every word through dictionary
3. Delete words that aren't listed in the dictionary

This could remove typos and words that are non-existent.

Comment: This will still misfiire on real-world text, for example where there are quotations of phrases in other languages. You can perhaps expect _raison d'être_ to be included in a comprehensive English word list, but probably not _kalsarikännit._

Comment: This was my initial thought, but was concerned about performance?

Comment: @devonuto What is your concern about the performance? Do you have limited computing power? With the right technologies this should be able to perform pretty good. If your text are really big you could even split them up and handle the parts asynchronously.

Comment: You could also include dictionaries of different languages. If you combine all of them into a single hash table it should perform medium-well even on older computers. I don't think there is another way to achieve your goal... besides some hyper AI stuff.

Comment: @MarkBaijens running on Azure, so I pay by how much processor I use.  So minimizing is the aim of the game.

Comment: Also needs to be able to recognize business names, which can be pronounceable, but not actual words (so they don't get removed).  So maybe something like what @tripleee posted above might be more useful in this regard.

Answer (score 1):

This will match words with more than 5 consonants (you probably want "y" to not be considered a consonant, but it's up to you):

```
\b[a-z]*[b-z&&[^aeiouy]]{6}[a-z]*\b
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/lTKvkIJYhA2Zib).

5 was chosen because I believe *witchcraft* has the longest chain of consonants of any English word. You could dial back "6" in the regex to say 5 or even 4 if you don't mind matching some outliers.

Comment: Hmm, interesting.  Guess it would be unlikely I would be finding many words with more than 5 in row. I will do some testing, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could train a simple model on sequences of characters which are permitted in the language(s) you want to support, and then flag any which contain sequences which are not in the training data.

The LangId language detector in SpamAssassin implements the Cavnar & Trenkle language-identification algorithm which basically uses a sliding window over the text and examines the adjacent 1 to 5 characters at each position. So from the training data "abracadabra" you would get

```
a 5
ab 2
abr 2
abra 2
abrac 1
b 2
br 2
bra 2
brac 1
braca 1
:
```

With enough data, you could build a model which identifies unusual patterns (my suggestion would be to try a window size of 3 or smaller for a start, and train it on several human languages from, say, Wikipedia) but it's hard to predict how precise exactly this will be.

SpamAssassin is written in Perl and it should not be hard to extract the language identification module.

As an alternative, there is a library called `libtextcat` which you can run standalone from C code if you like. The language identification in LibreOffice uses a fork which they adapted to use Unicode specifically, I believe (though it's been a while since I last looked at that).

Following Cavnar & Trenkle, all of these truncate the collected data to a few hundred patterns; you would probably want to extend this to cover up to all the 3-grams you find in your training data at least.

Perhaps see also Gertjan van Noord's link collection: https://www.let.rug.nl/vannoord/TextCat/

Depending on your test data, you could still get false positives e.g. on peculiar Internet domain names and long abbreviations. Tweak the limits for what you want to flag - I would think that GmbH should be okay even if you didn't train on German, but something like 7 or more letters long should probably be flagged and manually inspected.

Comment: "Sqiggles" is a curious corner case. Let me know if you tried this (-: